# Swift compiler error at the time of compiling

Tags: swift, ubuntu, swift5

Trying to compile a .swift file using the swift compiler in Ubuntu 19.10 but facing this error at the time of compilation.

```
$ swiftc swift.swift 
/usr/bin/ld.gold: fatal error: swift: open: Is a directory
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have also tried it with -v parameter and it shows this:

```
$ swiftc -v swift.swift 
Swift version 5.1 (swift-5.1.2-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
/home/takshaksh/swift/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -primary-file swift.swift -target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -disable-objc-interop -color-diagnostics -module-name swift -o /tmp/swift-2339bd.o
/home/takshaksh/swift/usr/bin/swift-autolink-extract /tmp/swift-2339bd.o -o /tmp/swift-0db3ba.autolink
/home/takshaksh/swift/usr/bin/clang++ -fuse-ld=gold -pie -target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /home/takshaksh/swift/usr/lib/swift/linux /home/takshaksh/swift/usr/lib/swift/linux/x86_64/swiftrt.o /tmp/swift-2339bd.o @/tmp/swift-0db3ba.autolink -L /home/takshaksh/swift/usr/lib/swift/linux -lswiftCore --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -v -o swift
clang version 7.0.0 
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/takshaksh/swift/usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/bin/ld.gold" -pie --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o swift /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbeginS.o -L/home/takshaksh/swift/usr/lib/swift/linux -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../.. -L/home/takshaksh/swift/usr/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib -rpath /home/takshaksh/swift/usr/lib/swift/linux /home/takshaksh/swift/usr/lib/swift/linux/x86_64/swiftrt.o /tmp/swift-2339bd.o -lswiftSwiftOnoneSupport -lswiftCore -lswiftCore -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

/usr/bin/ld.gold: fatal error: swift: open: Is a directory
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Can you share `swift.swift` ?

Comment: let versions = "It's Swift 5.1"
print(versions)

Comment: Just two lines that's it. The problem started to arise with Ubuntu 19.